# Count how many records belong to 2 categories in a n to n relation

Tags: mysql, count

I have a database containing articles whose schema is more or less the following:

```
COLLECTIONS ( PK id )
> 1 : n >
TOPICS ( PK id, FK collection_id )
> n : n >
TOPICS_TO_ARTICLES( FK topic_id, FK article_id )
> n : n >
ARTICLES ( PK id)
```

What I need is to find a way to understand how articles and collections are related, and one of the metrics is "how many articles belong to "collection 1" AND "collection 2". I thought I found a working query, but I think I'm missing something. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
  topics_to_articles AS TTA
INNER JOIN
  topics AS T ON T.id = TTA.topic_id
INNER JOIN
  articles AS A ON TTA.article_id = A.id
WHERE
  T.collection_id = cat_1_id AND A.status = 1 AND TTA.article_id IN(
  SELECT
    TTA2.article_id
  FROM
    topics_to_articles AS TTA2
  INNER JOIN
    topics AS T2 ON T2.id = TTA2.topic_id
  INNER JOIN
    articles AS A2 ON TTA2.article_id = A2.id
  WHERE
    T2.collection_id = cat_2_id AND A2.status = 1
)
```

I was pretty sure about this query being ok, but I noticed that if I invert the two "collection_id" variables (like c1 = 1 and c2 = 2 and then c2 = 1 and c1 = 2) I obtain two different results.

Is there a way to get that info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you join `topics` to `topics_to_articles` to `articles`, each article may be tied to multiple topics. And, multiple topics may be associated with each collection. So, you may be counting the same article multiple times.

For example:

- Collection A is tied to topics a,b,c
- Collection B is tied to topics b,d,e
- Article 1 is tied to topics a,b,e
- Article 2 is tied to topics a,c
- Article 3 is tied to topics b, d, e

If `cat_1_id` is 1 and `cat_2_id` is 2:

- the `IN` clause will contain article IDs 1 and 3 (while the query will list them more than once, the `IN` clause doesn't care how many times an ID is listed, just whether it's there or not)
- The main query will count:

  - article 1, topic a
  - article 1, topic b
  - article 1, topic c
  - article 3, topic b

If `cat_1_id` is 2 and `cat_2_id` is 1:

- the `IN` clause will contain article IDs 1, 2, and 3
- The main query will count:

  - article 1, topic b
  - article 1, topic e
  - article 3, topic b
  - article 3, topic d
  - article 3, topic e

The first query gives you 4; the second query gives you 5; you should really get 2 (because there are two distinct articles returned).

And, that word is the solution - `DISTINCT`

Change your two lines to:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT A.article_id) AS total
```

This way, when the same `article_id` shows up multiple times, it will still only be counted once.